# How same thing can be done in functional component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

I' getting the output in class-based component, but I want to know how the same thing can be done in functional component

```
class Apps extends React.Component {
  handleViewRef = ref => this.view = ref;

  bounce = () => this.view.bounce(800)

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{margin:60}}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.bounce}>
        <Animatable.View ref={this.handleViewRef}>
          <Text>Bounce me!</Text>
        </Animatable.View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I want when a user press button animation should happen, the same thing I have done using class component it is working but  I want using functional component  please refer this link same thing I have done in a class component [link] **(https://snack.expo.io/@sushil62/55950b)**  @Tim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use hooks to achieve this:

```
const App = ()=>{
  const const viewRef = useRef(null);
  const bounce = useCallback(() => {
    if (viewRef.current) {
      viewRef.current.bounce(800)
    }, [viewRef]
  );
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={bounce} style={styles.container}>
         <Button ref={viewRef} rounded warning>
            <Text>Warning</Text>
          </Button>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <Apps/>
      </View>
    );
}
```

The `useCallback` is not strictly necessary but will prevent re-creating the `bounce` callback on every render. See https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref and https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: Hi,@azundo can you check this [link](https://snack.expo.io/@sushil62/55950b) what is the issue with it

Comment: You're using a NativeBase `Button` in the `App` component which doesn't have a `bounce` method. If you swap the `Button` for the same `Animatable.View` you're using in the `Apps` component you'll see that the hooks code works as expected.